# Efficiency when inserting huge data into a database

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I want to insert huge amount of data into database, which way is more efficient?
1. insert data row by row by calling insert statement
2. create a user defined Table type in my database, and write a stored procedure to insert a DataTable into database.
and why?

Comment: [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) is probably the best approach in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient would be  [**SQL Bulk Insert**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

To improve the performance further you can use [**SqlBulkCopy** to SQL Server **in Parallel**](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/01/sqlbulkcopy-to-sql-server-in-parallel.html).

Comment: Yeah, I searched for the SQL Bulk Insert, and found it powerful. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably vary based on the specific workload.

We can only tell you here what options are available to you - it is down to you to measure how efficient each option is in your specific case.

Options:

- `SQLBulkCopy`
- `INSERT` statements with single row
- `INSERT` statements with multiple rows (experiment with different numbers of rows)
- Stored procedure (with variations on the above)

Answer (score 0):

2 is much much faster, because anything that involves per-row operations ([RBAR](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/)) is inherently slow. I did quite a lot of testing with table valued parameters and found them to be close to the performance of bulk inserts for batch sizes of up to 1,000,000 rows. However, that's purely anecdotal and your mileage may vary.

Also, I would advise against using a `DataTable` and write something that streamed the rows more directly. I blogged about that [here](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/blog/post/2011/05/21/A-generic-list-for-passing-table-valued-parameters-to-SQL-Server.aspx).